# Loading Javascript and CSS files without DNS calls

Tags: javascript, php, css, .htaccess, dns

If I reference  javascript files in my header using full domain names is it slower to load than if I do it some other way?

```
$domain = 'https://www.example.com';
echo '<script src="'.$domain.'/js/index.js"></script>';
```

The problem is if I wasn't going to reference them directly I would need some way of handling it so they load even if the page is rewritten to a subfolder like `https://www.example.com/subfolder/subfolder` using .htaccess rewrite rules.

Is there a better, faster to load, yet still flexible way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confusing absolute URIs with a requirement for a DNS lookup.

Given an HTML document on `http://example.com/index.html` then the only difference between these two script elements:

```
<script src="/foo.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/foo.js"></script>
```

… is that the latter has an additional 18 bytes of HTML (which is insignificant even before you apply HTTP compression).

Whichever of the two approaches you use, the browser is going to resolve the URL to `http://example.com/foo.js`. If it has `example.com` in its DNS cache (which it will because it just loaded the HTML document), then it won't hit DNS servers to find out where to go for it.

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
echo '<script src="'.$domain.'/js/index.js"></script>';
```

Comment: Well I'm concerned about DNS calls slowing my website - what will $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] produce?

Comment: Hmmmm that gives www.example.com - wouldn't that still cause a dns call?

Comment: your project is placed inside this path `https://www.example.com/subfolder/subfolder` ??

Comment: This will print host name where you been